# How to solve TypeError: on_delete must be callable on Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, cascade

Suddenly I am getting an error saying `TypeError: on_delete must be callable.` I don't know how to solve this error as I don't see `field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete='CASCADE', to='main.Category'),` mentioned anywhere in my code.

```
  File "/home/arch/myproject/main/migrations/0014_auto_20191025_1154.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
  File "/home/arch/myproject/main/migrations/0014_auto_20191025_1154.py", line 47, in Migration
    field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete='CASCADE', to='main.Category'),
  File "/home/arch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 801, in __init__
    raise TypeError('on_delete must be callable.')
```

TypeError: on_delete must be callable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A field in one of your models has:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # …
    field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete='CASCADE', to='main.Category')
```

but you can not pass a string to `on_delete=…` parameter, it should be:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    # …
    field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to='main.Category')
```

You will need to remove the migration file (`main/migrations/0014_auto_20191025_1154.py`) as well, and make new migrations.

Comment: Now I get `raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration main.0015_auto_20191025_1159 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('main', '0014_auto_20191025_1154')` when I run`python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: @GTA.sprx: that is because you apparently made other migration files with a dependency on this one. You thus need to remove `main/migrations/0015_auto_20191025_1159.py` as well (and perhaps others)

Comment: Transitioning from Django 1.11 to 3.0, `'cascade'` used to be in migrations, I changed it to `models.CASCADE` and now it works. thx

Answer (score 0):

According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete), the `on_delete` argument must be a callable, not a string.

Here's the `CASCADE` callable defined in `django.db.models`:

```
def CASCADE(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
    collector.collect(sub_objs, source=field.remote_field.model,
                      source_attr=field.name, nullable=field.null)
    if field.null and not connections[using].features.can_defer_constraint_checks:
        collector.add_field_update(field, None, sub_objs)
```