# TypeError: on_delete must be callable. ('on_delete must be callable.')

Tags: django, django-models

**I have done a project three month before. Now when i downloaded the code from github and run the server I am facing this issue.**

"/home/shivam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 801, in **init**
    raise TypeError('on_delete must be callable.')
TypeError: on_delete must be callable.

My files are.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class BRMuser(models.Model):
    user  = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete="models.CASCADE")
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from BRMapp.forms import NewBookForm,SearchForm
from BRMapp.models import Book
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login,logout


# Create your views here.
def userLogin(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/BRMapp/view-books')
        else:
            data['error']="UserName and Password are incorrect"
            res = render(request,'BRMapp/user_login.html', data)
            return res
    else:
        return render(request,'BRMapp/user_login.html',data)

def userLogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('BRMapp/login/')

def viewBooks(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    res=render(request,'BRMapp/view_book.html',{'books':books})
    return res

def editBook(request):
     book = Book.objects.get(id=request.GET['bookid'])
     fields= {'title':book.title,'price':book.price,'author':book.author,'publisher':book.publisher}
     form = NewBookForm(initial=fields)
     res = render(request,'BRMapp/edit_book.html', {'form':form, 'book':book})
     return res

def deleteBook(request):
    bookid = request.GET['bookid']
    book = Book.objects.get(id=bookid)
    book.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('view-books')

def searchBook(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    res = render(request,'BRMapp/search_book.html', {'form':form})
    return res

def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)
    books = Book.objects.filter(title= form.data['title'])
    res = render(request, 'BRMapp/search_book.html', {'books':books, 'form':form})
    return res

def edit(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = NewBookForm(request.POST)
        book= Book()
        book.id=request.POST['bookid']
        book.title = form.data['title']
        book.price = form.data['price']
        book.author= form.data['author']
        book.publisher = form.data['publisher']
        book.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('view-books')

def newBook(request):
    form = NewBookForm()
    res = render(request,'BRMapp/new_book.html',{'form':form})
    return res


def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewBookForm(request.POST)
        book = Book()
        book.title= form.data['title']
        book.price = form.data['price']
        book.author = form.data['author']
        book.publisher = form.data['publisher']
        book.save()
    s="Record Stored <br> <a href='/BRMapp/view-books'> View All Books</a>"
    return HttpResponse(s)
[My server response][1]

I think there is a minor mistake.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: on\_delete must be callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272494/typeerror-on-delete-must-be-callable)

Comment: I had seen the question before posting my question but i did't get the answer

Comment: You need to replace `on_delete="models.CASCADE"` with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`. (Removed quotation signs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the quotes from "models.CASCADE"